# AWS EKSにてPodからのcurlをservice名で実行できない

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

初めてEKSに触っています。

### やったこと：

- [Amazon EKS の開始方法 – AWS Management Console と AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html)
- [サンプルアプリケーションをデプロイする](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/eks/latest/userguide/sample-deployment.html)

上記ドキュメント通りに進め(たつもりですが)、PodにシェルでアクセスしServerへcurlを実行するところまで行いました。
cloudformation, yaml等はドキュメントのまま実施。
Fargateで行いたかったので、名前空間`eks-sample-app`を含むFargateプロファイルを作成。
このとき、curlがservice名だとうまくいかなかったので、Endpointで行なってみています。

```
$ kubectl get pods -n eks-sample-app
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
eks-sample-linux-deployment-5b568bf897-4fh8g   1/1     Running   0          5m8s
```

```
$ kubectl -n eks-sample-app describe service eks-sample-linux-service
Name:              eks-sample-linux-service
Namespace:         eks-sample-app
Labels:            app=eks-sample-linux-app
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=eks-sample-linux-app
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.100.161.222
IPs:               10.100.161.222
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.204.16:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

```
$ kubectl exec -it eks-sample-linux-deployment-5b568bf897-4fh8g -n eks-sample-app -- /bin/bash
root@eks-sample-linux-deployment-5b568bf897-4fh8g:/# curl eks-sample-linux-service
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: eks-sample-linux-service
root@eks-sample-linux-deployment-5b568bf897-4fh8g:/# curl 192.168.204.16:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
・・・・・・
```

```
$ kubectl get all -n kube-system
NAME                                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/coredns-8496bbc677-fztvq                        0/1     Pending   0          19h
pod/coredns-8496bbc677-xzxtd                        0/1     Pending   0          19h

NAME                                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/kube-dns                            ClusterIP   10.100.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   19h

NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/aws-node     0         0         0       0            0           <none>          19h
daemonset.apps/kube-proxy   0         0         0       0            0           <none>          19h

NAME                                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/coredns                        0/2     2            0           19h

NAME                                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/coredns-8496bbc677                        2         2         0       19h
```

そもそも、この設定が足りないなどあればご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fargateで行いたかったので、名前空間eks-sample-appを含むFargateプロファイルを作成。
> 関係あるかわかりませんが、このとき、なぜかcurlがservice名だとうまくいかなかったので、Endpointで行なってみています。

AWS Load Balancer Controller以前にFargateでのKubernetes環境が正しく構築できていません。具体的には

> ```
> pod/coredns-8496bbc677-fztvq                        0/1     Pending   0          19h
> pod/coredns-8496bbc677-xzxtd                        0/1     Pending   0          19h
> ```

CoreDNSが正常動作できていません。これについては[Amazon EKS を使用した AWS Fargate の使用開始](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html)に

> ### CoreDNS の更新

がありますが、これを実行できていないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
リンクを参考にクラスターの作成からやり直してみました。

CoreDNSは正常に動作でき、サンプルアプリにおいてのcurlでは、サービス名でも実行できるようになったのを確認しました。
ただ、aws-load-balancer-controllerに関して変わらずPendingとなってしまっています。

他に何か考えられる点はないでしょうか？
必要な情報等あれば追記していきます。

Comment: @owatata 私はあなたの家庭教師ではありませんし、SOjaは一問一答式です。本件は質問文後半を削除し「curlがservice名だとうまくいかな」いとして私の回答をもって解決済みとし、AWS Load Balancer Controllerについては改めて質問し直してください。その際、手順をやり直し新たなエラーメッセージを記述してください。

Comment: 失礼しました。
本質が解決してなくても一旦閉じるもんなんですね。
確かに、開示する情報程度という甘い認識ですみませんでしたが、解決していただいたのには代わりないのでそのように致します。